How to Prevent Chrome Pop-Up Asking for Permission Every Time when the extension refresh the page
I am using the Auto Refresh Plus extension in Chrome to automatically refresh a webpage. However, a pop-up appears each time, requiring me to manually click the "Continue" button. This interrupts the automatic refresh process and requires manual input.
Is there a way to handle this pop-up automatically, so that the "Continue" button is selected on its own and the refresh process can proceed uninterrupted? I am open to any solutions that can help automate this step, whether through additional settings, custom code, or other extensions.
I tried using the Auto Refresh Plus extension in Chrome to automatically refresh a webpage at regular intervals. My expectation was that the page would refresh without requiring any manual interaction, so it could operate seamlessly in the background. However, I encountered an issue: a pop-up appears after each refresh, requiring me to click a "Continue" button. This disrupts the automation, as it demands manual input to proceed.
To resolve this, I explored the settings within the extension to see if there was an option to bypass or automatically dismiss this pop-up, but I couldn’t find a suitable solution. I’m looking for a way to either automatically handle the pop-up by selecting "Continue" or another method to allow uninterrupted refreshing without manual intervention.

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/chromium-browser-automati/jmbmjnojfkcohdpkpjmeeijckfbebbon?hl=de&pli=1
Maybe some web automation addons could help you out.
